# change character in all text fields

Tags: ms-access, replace, vba

I need your help. I woulod like to change one char by another but in all database and i have several table and fields. So i'm building a function in VB but that change nothing and i have no error. I think that my condition is false but i don't see how to correct it :/

```
Public Sub updateField()
Dim db As DAO.Database, td As DAO.TableDef, field As DAO.field
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, sSQL As String, sData As String

Set db = CurrentDb

Change = "\"""
replaced = """"

'each table in db
For Each tbd In db.TableDefs
    'each field in table
    For Each fld In tbd.Fields
        'check if String Data have my character
        If InStr(1, fld.Name, Change) Then
            sSQL = "UPDATE " & tbd.Name & " SET " & fld.Name & " = replace([" & fld.Name & "], " & Change & ", " & replaced & ")"
            db.Execute sSQL
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

EDIT :
I finally find what's wrong. if some people are interested :

```
Set db = CurrentDb

Change = "\"""
replaced = """"

'each table in db
For Each tbd In db.TableDefs
    'each field in table
    For Each fld In tbd.Fields
        If Left(tbd.Name, 4) <> "MSys" And Left(tbd.Name, 4) <> "~TMP" Then
            If fld.Type = dbText Or fld.Type = dbMemo Then
                sSQL = "UPDATE " & tbd.Name & " SET " & fld.Name & " = replace([" & fld.Name & "],'" & Chr(92) + Chr(34) & "','" & Chr(34) & "')"
                db.Execute sSQL
                'Debug.Print (sSQL)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Thx for your help guys ;)

Comment: Ick, the old DAO objects. I feel dirty just reading this.

Comment: so you're wanting to change the name of fields in the database? or the data values stored in those fields? Your logic seems to be trying to replace field names, not values.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to change the values in field ^^ but i don't know how made this :/ Thx

Comment: so you are trying to replace `"` with `\"` is that correct?

Comment: Yes i'm trying to replace \" by " in value Fields.

Comment: Try `replace([" & fld.Name & "],'" & Chr(92) & "','')"`

Comment: FYI..  I will be willing to be there is something here for you to leverage..  ;)  http://www.candace-tripp.net/Pages/Main.aspx?cat=demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it should help there my solution :

```
Public Sub updateField()
Dim db As DAO.Database, td As DAO.TableDef, field As DAO.field
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, sSQL As String, sData As String, change As String, replace As String

change = "\'"
replace = "'"

' simple quote = 39
' doulbe quote = 34
' antislash = 92
' retour chariot = 13
' n = 110
' r = 114
Set db = CurrentDb

'each table in db
For Each tbd In db.TableDefs
    'each field in table
    For Each fld In tbd.Fields
        If Left(tbd.Name, 4) <> "MSys" And Left(tbd.Name, 4) <> "~TMP" Then
            If fld.Type = dbText Or fld.Type = dbMemo Then
                ' \r\n
                'sSQL = "UPDATE " & tbd.Name & " SET [" & fld.Name & "] = replace([" & fld.Name & "],'\r\n','" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "');"
                ' \"
                'sSQL = "UPDATE " & tbd.Name & " SET [" & fld.Name & "] = replace([" & fld.Name & "],'" & Chr(92) + Chr(34) & "','" & Chr(34) & "');"
                'db.Execute sSQL
                sSQL = "UPDATE " & tbd.Name & " SET [" & fld.Name & "] = replace([" & fld.Name & "],'\''','''');"
                db.Execute sSQL
                'Debug.Print (sSQL)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

That's works for me ;)